# if $2^n+1=xy$, show $2^a|(x-1) \iff 2^a|(y-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Suppose that $2^n+1=xy$, where $x$ and $y$ are integers greater than $1$ and $n>0$. Show that $2^a|(x-1)$ if and only if $2^a|(y-1)$.

What I noticed is that $2^n+1$ is an odd number for any $n$, so $x$ and $y$ are both odd numbers, and hence $x-1$ and $y-1$ will always be even. So here is what I did,

Let $x-1=2^bd_{1}$ and $y-1=2^cd_{2}$, where $b,c>0$ and $d_{1},d_{2}$ are odd natural numbers. So,

$\begin{align*}
2^n+1 & = (2^bd_{1}+1)(2^cd_{2}+1) \\
& = 2^{b+c}d_{1}d_{2}+2^bd_{1}+2^cd_{2}+1 \\
2^n & =  2^{b+c}d_{1}d_{2}+2^bd_{1}+2^cd_{2}
\end{align*} $

if $2^a|(x-1)$ for some $a$, then $b\ge a$, so in the above equation, $2^a|2^n$,$2^a|2^{b+c}d_{1}d_{2}$ and $2^a|2^bd_{1}$, this implies $2^a|2^cd_{2} \implies c\ge a$. Hence $2^a|(y-1)$. The other implication can be proved in a similar way.

Is this approach correct? Am I missing something? Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your title uses $2^a$ twice, while your question body problem statement uses $2^a$ and $2^b$. Which is right? Also, what are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected

Comment: $a,b$ and $c$ are positive integers.

Comment: Hint: if $\,xy\equiv 1\,$ then $\,x\equiv 1\iff y\equiv 1,\,$ i.e. it boils down to $\, 1^{-1}\equiv 1\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite $$2^n+1=xy$$ as $$2^n=(x-1)(y-1)+(x-1)+(y-1)$$

With this equation, we can easily see that for every integer $a$ with $\ 1\le a\le n\ $ , $\ x-1\ $ is divisible by $\ 2^a\ $ if and only if $\ y-1\ $ is divisble by $\ 2^a\ $ , which is what has to be proven.

With some additional considerations, we can also show the claim for other non-negative integers $\ a\ $ , which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize that the expression can be rewritten in this way. This certainly makes it easier.

Comment: @sam Such rewriting obfuscates the algebraic essence of the matter, which is simply that $\,1^{-1}\equiv 1,\,$ i.e.  $$\large {\rm if}\ \,xy\equiv 1\,\  {\rm then} \,\ x\equiv 1\!\iff\! y\equiv 1\ \ \qquad\qquad$$